# Algorith to convert .amr to .wav in j2me

Tags: java-me, midlet, audioformat

I would like to know the algorithm for converting .amr to .wav . What I have done till now is remove the .amr header and replace it with .wav header.The format gets changed but the audio plays some vague sound. I think this is because the raw data of .amr is different. How do I convert this to .wav?